# Ng-bootstrap Pulldown menu is not activated on table row with click handler

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

The user can click on a table row to see the details.

When adding a 'ng-bootstrap' **pulldown menu** in the last column of the data table, clicking on the pulldown button will never open the pulldown menu. So, clicking on the button will navigate to the details page.

Normally I have an 'edit' icon in the last column. Clicking on the icon (button) will start that action. The click handler on the button will get precedence over de row click handler.

Why is that? How can I prevent that?

A simplified version of the data table is:

```html
<tr class="row" *ngFor="let dataRow of datarows.rows; let i = index (click)="editDataRowDetails(dataRow)">
  <td class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1">{{dataRow.data1}}</td>

  <!-- a number of table columns --> 

  <td class="col-1 col-md-1">
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Actions</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button (click)="doAction( 'Errors', dataRow.id)" ngbDropdownItem>Errors</button>
        <button (click)="doAction( 'Events', dataRow.id)" ngbDropdownItem>Events</button>
        <button (click)="doAction( 'Counts', dataRow.id)" ngbDropdownItem>Counts</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The app is built with Angular 12 and Ng-Bootstrap. Other ng-bootstrap components are working fine.

```json
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding a `stopPropagation()` call when clicking the drop down button.

notice the `(click)="open($event)"` on the `ngbDropdownToggle` button and the added `open` function in the component.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nydrz3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```html
<tr class="row" *ngFor="let dataRow of data" (click)="edit(dataRow)">
  <td class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1">{{ dataRow.data1 }}</td>

  <!-- a number of table columns -->

  <td class="col-1 col-md-1">
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button
        class="btn btn-outline-primary"
        ngbDropdownToggle
        (click)="open($event)"
      >
        Actions
      </button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button (click)="action('Errors', dataRow.id)" ngbDropdownItem>
          Errors
        </button>
        <button (click)="action('Events', dataRow.id)" ngbDropdownItem>
          Events
        </button>
        <button (click)="action('Counts', dataRow.id)" ngbDropdownItem>
          Counts
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

interface DataRow {
  data1: string;
  id: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  data: DataRow[] = [
    {
      data1: 'some Data',
      id: '1',
    },
  ];

  edit(row: DataRow) {
    console.log('edit called');
  }

  action(type: string, id: string) {
    console.log('action called');
  }

  open(event) {
    console.log('open called');
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also had to add the stopPropagation to the action().